# Visual studio resolution

Tags: visual-studio

I was making a form on visual studio and didn't realise that my resolution was at 300% as I was working off a TV, all my items appeared scrunched together so I reset them in the correct positions however now some of them are off the edges of the form and I cant stretch it past a certain point in order to move them back. Is there a way I could get them without having to remake it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Visual Studio are you using? In the latest versions you can use the Document Outline pane/window (View->Other Windows->Document Outline, Ctrl-Alt-T may also display it).

In that window, with the form displayed, it will list all the controls in the form. Find the ones you need, right-click on them and select Properties.

Now the Properties window should be showing the properties for that control. You should now be able to edit the Location there to adjust where the control is posistioned.

Comment: Thanks this worked, I also realised that when I was in the design view for the form there is an option at the top of the properties window which is a dropdown selection of all the different controls on the form

Comment: Glad I could help. I forgot to mention you can also use tab to go to each of the controls in the designer but if you have a lot of them it is difficult to see where you are.